# How to create a constructor using a hash table with Vectors (separate Chaining)

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, hashtable

I am trying to create a constructor for a hash table of vectors for separate chaining. I keep getting an error that says:

error: expected primary-expression before 'table'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <stdexcept>

// Custom project includes
#include "Hash.h"

// Namespaces to include
using std::vector;
using std::list;
using std::pair;

//
// Separate chaining based hash table - inherits from Hash
//
template<typename K, typename V>
class ChainingHash : public Hash<K,V> {
private:
    vector<list<V>> table;          // Vector of Linked lists

public:
    ChainingHash(int n = 11) {

        table = vector<list<K,V>> table(n);

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This line makes no sense.  You are trying to combine an assignment expression with a variable definition statement.  Not only that, but you have `list<K,V>` which makes no sense when your stored table wants `list<V>`...

```
table = vector<list<K,V>> table(n);  // <-- completely broken syntax
```

To initialize your table in the constructor, all you need to do is use an initializer list:

```
ChainingHash(int n = 11)
    : table(n)
{
}
```

With the above constructor definition, the `table` member will be initialized with `n` empty lists, which appears to be what you were trying to do.